# How to use placeholders?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a placeholder on my page and I can't seem to get it to do a simple hyperlink. Surely I am missing something? Here is the code:

word.aspx

```html
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

or

```html
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and the code behind:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts

Partial Public Class Word
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim hyperlink1 As New HyperLink()
        hyperlink1.Text = "Devmanuals"
        hyperlink1.NavigateUrl = "http://www.devmanuals.com/"
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.AddAt(0, hyperlink1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

or

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts

Partial Public Class Word
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim hyperlink1 As New HyperLink()
        hyperlink1.Text = "Devmanuals"
        hyperlink1.NavigateUrl = "http://www.devmanuals.com/"
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(hyperlink1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I haven't gotten either way to work.

Comment: That code *should* add a new `HyperLink` to `PlaceHolder1`.  After the call to `.Add()` can you see the `HyperLink` in the `Controls` collection for `PlaceHolder1` when debugging?  Is there any markup added to the rendered page at all?

Comment: Have you tried adding your code to the Page_Init event instead of load? Could be a page life cycle issue...

Comment: I meant to add the markup as well. But to answer your question, David, no, there is no markup. Jason, I'll give it a shot. I assume you mean to simply change Page_Load to Page_Init?

Comment: As far as what I can tell, the method should work. It should simply be `Placeholder1.Controls.Add(yourNewControl)`.
What if you try adding a `Placeholder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("TEST"))`  - will that be displayed on your page?

Comment: Nope. Am I not importing something? Also, still nothing in the markup.

Comment: @Joseph Is it possible that any other part of your code sets `PlaceHolder1.Visible = False` ? If not - can you try explicitly set for the hyperlink `hyperlink1.Visible = True` ?

Comment: Set the Visible property to true and still nothing :(

Comment: Can u put a breakpoint to make sure the code runs at all? If it does - can u the Hyperlink in controls collection of the placeholder? Also, does it work if (as a test) you replace Placehodler with Panel?

Comment: When I run the page, the HTML doesn't show that anything is there.